# Video Streaming

Tags: video-streaming

I would like videos get downloaded as it plays, and site is in godaddy shared hosting.They said it can be done but they cannot open up streaming ports on a shared plan and they recommended flash method. If anybody know about this, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I used VLC player, it can be an option, coming with ActiveX.